Correct language/syntax for the Request Body field in the HTTP Request Widget when Form URL Encoded is the content type
I'm using Twilio Studio Flow to enter a new row into a Google sheet when a WhatsApp message comes in. And it works when I configure the HTTP Request Widget with JSON as the CONTENT TYPE. But I needed to switch to Form URL Encoded as the CONTENT TYPE, and now it's adding empty rows to my sheet (except for the timestamp). When I used JSON, I used this as my REQUEST BODY in the HTTP Request Widget and it worked perfectly:
{
"From":"{{widgets.max.inbound.From}}",
"Body":"{{widgets.max.inbound.Body}}"
}

But then I changed the REQUEST BODY to this for the Form URL Encoded CONTENT TYPE, and it's sending empty values:
From={{widgets.min.inbound.From}}&Body={{widgets.min.inbound.Body}}

I have this as my Apps Script code:
// Function to handle incoming HTTP POST requests
function doPostAddRow(e) {
  // Access parameters directly from the request
  var from = e.parameter.From;
  var body = e.parameter.Body;

  // Log the values for debugging
  Logger.log("From: " + from);
  Logger.log("Body: " + body);

  // Get active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Create a new row with timestamp, from, and body
  var newRow = [from, body, new Date()];

  // Append the new row to the sheet
  sheet.appendRow(newRow);

  // Return success message
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
}

Apps Script is not returning any logs

About When I used JSON, I used this as my REQUEST BODY in the HTTP Request Widget and it worked perfectly, can you provide the details of the request? Also, about But then I changed the REQUEST BODY to this for the Form URL Encoded CONTENT TYPE, and it's sending empty values:, can you provide the details of the request? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Sure, in both cases the HTTP Request widget in my Twilio Flow was configured to POST as the REQUEST METHOD and the HTTP paramaterers were set to KEY: webapp and VALUE: webapp1.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand both requests. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

No worries, I appreciate the help. My HTTP Request has to be Form URL encoded.. In my Twilio Flow Studio, I have to define the REQUEST BODY for the From and Body values that I will use in the JavaScript. But my JavaScript is not handling the data correctly or it is not receiving any data. Because it's adding an empty row (except for the Timestamp) But I can't seem to log anything either. Does this make sense?

Thank you for replying. In your situation, when I could correctly understand both HTTP requests in your question, it might help think of a solution. But, unfortunately, from your reply and your question, I cannot still understand them. So, I cannot still think of a solution. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for my poor English skill again. For example, can you provide the curl commands for both HTTP requests in your question?

I use Twilio Flow Studio, it doesn't have curl commands, it has some fields to complete for the http request. My fields are CONTENT TYPE: Form URL Encoded and REQUEST BODY: From={{widgets.min.inbound.From}}&Body={{widgets.min.inbound.Body}}. I did manage to get the logs to work though. The logs show Body: undefined From: undefined

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to try to think of your HTTP requests.

I managed to get it to work. My code is a bit messy, but it works:
function doPostAddRow(e) {
  // Parse the POST data to extract parameters
  var postData = e.postData.contents;
  Logger.log(postData);
  var decodedData = decodeURIComponent(postData);
  Logger.log(decodedData)
  var params = decodedData.split("&");
  Logger.log(params)
  // Initialize variables to store values
  var body;
  
  // Iterate through parameters to extract values - this is just getting the body
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var index = params[i].indexOf("=");
    var key = params[i].substring(0, index);
    var value = params[i].substring(index + 1);
    if (key === "From") {
      from = value;
    } else if (key === "Body") {
      body = value;
    }
  }
  
  var from = extractFromParameter(decodedData);

  // Log the values for debugging
  Logger.log("From: " + from);
  Logger.log("Body: " + body);

  // Get active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Create a new row with timestamp, from, and body
  var newRow = [from, body, new Date()];

  // Append the new row to the sheet
  sheet.appendRow(newRow);

  // Return success message
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
}

//extract the From value from the Form URL Encoded data in line 20
function extractFromParameter(decodedData) {
    const regex = /From=([^&]*)/;
    const match = decodedData.match(regex);
    if (match && match[1]) {
        return match[1];
    } else {
        return null; // or whatever you want to return if "From=" parameter is not found
    }
}

